# Claims - Tangible difference between system claims and method claims - 101 thoughts

Tags: claims, claim-construction

Does a system claim which state tangible items, for example "processor configured to" help satisfy the "practical application" aspect of the new guidelines which were released in January 2019?  I am also looking for any definitions in MPEP which define a method claim as well as a system claim.  According to the MPEP, are they really different or merely a different flavor?

Answer (score 2):

35 USC 101 says -

> Whoever invents or discovers any new and useful **process**, **machine**, manufacture, or composition of matter, or any new and useful improvement thereof, may obtain a patent therefor, subject to the conditions and requirements of this title.

A **method** is a process and a **system** is a machine. They are clearly in two different statutory categories.

EDIT

If you mix things (system, for example) and steps (methods) in a single claim it will be ruled as indefinite.

From MPEP

I.    PRODUCT AND PROCESS IN THE SAME CLAIM

> A single claim which claims both an apparatus and the method steps of
>   using the apparatus is indefinite under 35 U.S.C. 112(b) or pre-AIA 35
>   U.S.C. 112, second paragraph. See In re Katz Interactive Call
>   Processing Patent Litigation, 639 F.3d 1303, 1318, 97 USPQ2d 1737,
>   1748-49 (Fed. Cir. 2011). In Katz, a claim directed to "[a] system
>   with an interface means for providing automated voice messages…to
>   certain of said individual callers, wherein said certain of said
>   individual callers digitally enter data" was determined to be
>   indefinite because the italicized claim limitation is not directed to
>   the system, but rather to actions of the individual callers, which
>   creates confusion as to when direct infringement occurs. Katz, 639
>   F.3d at 1318 (citing IPXL Holdings v. Amazon.com, Inc., 430 F.3d 1377,
>   1384, 77 USPQ2d 1140, 1145 (Fed. Cir. 2005), in which a system claim
>   that recited "an input means" and required a user to use the input
>   means was found to be indefinite because it was unclear "whether
>   infringement … occurs when one creates a system that allows the user
>   [to use the input means], or whether infringement occurs when the user
>   actually uses the input means."); Ex parte Lyell, 17 USPQ2d 1548 (Bd.
>   Pat. App. & Inter. 1990) (claim directed to an automatic transmission
>   workstand and the method of using it held ambiguous and properly
>   rejected under 35 U.S.C. 112, second paragraph).

MORE EDITING

A way claim wording can cross the line into including both steps and a claim for a system is that system claims can be written as a system that is defined by its behavior. That can be a legitimate way to define a system. But defining the behavior is usually done as steps. "A system configured to execute . . . " is frequently seen in a claim preamble. Even though a definition of what looks like a method follows, this is *not* a method claim.

If this type of claim is attempted and not worded correctly it can be ambiguous as to whether a thing or a method is being claimed.

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd prong test of Step 2A of "2019 Revised Patent Subject Matter Eligibility Guidance", "practical application" is to be 'evaluated on the claim as a whole'(note 24 page') [1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2018-28282.pdf).

The term 'additional element' requirement in this context connotes 'claim features, limitations, and/or steps that are recited in the claim beyond the identified judicial exception, (same note)[1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2018-28282.pdf)

Hence, it may be construed that mere mention of a tangible item is not enough. What is required is integration of 'judicial exception' to a 'practical application'(e.g. note 26 page 20 of [1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2018-28282.pdf)).

If, your "processor configured to" is 'aimed to' usher any improvement in any practical application (e.g. improvement in field of computer technology, computer performance etc (note 25) [1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2018-28282.pdf)) than (if 102, 103 and 112 do not stand on your way) perhaps.

As regards "definitions in MPEP" for definition of "method claim as well as a system claim", I too looked for the same for years but could not locate one. However, these two documents may be useful for you. Patent claim Formats and Types of Claims from WIPO [2](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/mdocs/aspac/en/wipo_ip_phl_16/wipo_ip_phl_16_t5.pdf) and also this one from USPTO [3](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Website%20PDF%20-%20Invention%20Con%202017%20Claim%20Drafting%20Workshop%20-%20OPLA.pdf)

This site also is rich with highly educative content on this subject e.g [4](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20167/what-is-a-difference-between-system-claims-and-method-claims). Please search tab related to question to find them out.